# Get two arrays from function and store them in different data type array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, data-structures

I have a function which contains more than one array and I want to use those two arrays in my main function in this way

```
void fun ()    //which data type should I place here int OR char ?
{
    int array[4]={1,2,3,4}
    char array2[3]={'a','b','c'}

    return array,array2;
}
```

```
int main(){

    int array1[4];
    char array2[3];


    array1=fun();  is it possible to get these array here ?
    array2=fun();
}
```

Comment: No, that's not possible this way.

Comment: Just make a struct with two arrays. E.g. `struct myfunc_retval_t { std::array<int,4> array1; std::array<char,3> array2; }; and return that. It is explicit and very clear what your intentions are

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to *return* arrays, you could put them in a `std::pair` of `std::array`s:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <utility>

auto fun() {
    std::pair<std::array<int, 4>, std::array<char, 3>> rv{
        {1, 2, 3, 4},
        { 'a', 'b', 'c' }
    };

    return rv;
}

int main() {
    auto[ints, chars] = fun();
}
```

Comment: The one thing I do not like about pairs is that they are a bit implicit with the first and second member variables. I always need to look back at code what first means and what second means. It is little effort to make an explicit struct with clearer names.

Answer (score 2):

Using a struct, code would look like this (using range based for loops for output).

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

// struct holding two arrays with clear names
struct myfun_retval_t
{
    std::array<int, 4> integers;
    std::array<char, 3> characters;
};

// function returning the struct with two arrays
myfun_retval_t myfun()
{
    myfun_retval_t retval
    {
        {1,2,3,4},
        {'a','b','c'}
    };

    return retval;
}

int main()
{
    // call function and store result
    auto retval = myfun();

    // then output content, using clear readable names for the arrays

    for (const int value : retval.integers)
    {
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    for (const char c : retval.characters)
    {
        std::cout << c << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::tuple` of `std:array`s:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<std::array<int, 4>, std::array<char, 3>> fun() 
{
    std::array<int, 4> a1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    std::array<char, 3> a2 = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
    return std::make_tuple(a1, a2);
}

int main()
{
    auto mixedArrays = fun();
    
    for (const auto& i : std::get<0>(mixedArrays))
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    
    for (const auto& i : std::get<1>(mixedArrays))
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://cpp.sh/?source=%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0D%0A%23include+%3Carray%3E%0D%0A%23include+%3Ctuple%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Astd%3A%3Atuple%3Cstd%3A%3Aarray%3Cint%2C+4%3E%2C+std%3A%3Aarray%3Cchar%2C+3%3E%3E+fun()+%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++++std%3A%3Aarray%3Cint%2C+4%3E+a1+%3D+%7B+1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4+%7D%3B%0D%0A++++std%3A%3Aarray%3Cchar%2C+3%3E+a2+%3D+%7B+%27a%27%2C+%27b%27%2C+%27c%27+%7D%3B%0D%0A++++return+std%3A%3Amake_tuple(a1%2C+a2)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aint+main()%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++++auto+mixedArrays+%3D+fun()%3B%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++for+(const+auto%26+i+%3A+std%3A%3Aget%3C0%3E(mixedArrays))%0D%0A++++%7B%0D%0A++++++++std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C+i+%3C%3C+std%3A%3Aendl%3B%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++for+(const+auto%26+i+%3A+std%3A%3Aget%3C1%3E(mixedArrays))%0D%0A++++%7B%0D%0A++++++++std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C+i+%3C%3C+std%3A%3Aendl%3B%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A%7D)

This way you can extend the code to make `fun()` return more stuff in the future if need be.

Answer (score -1):

Pass pointers to your arrays in `main` to your function

Like this

```
void fun(int* array, char* array2)
{
    ...
}

int main()
{
    int array1[4];
    char array2[3];
    fun(array1, array2);
}
```

Hopefully that will get you started, but really you need to read about arrays and pointers and function parameters in your C++ book. This is a complicated topic, and one that many newbies get wrong.

Comment: Using this alternative I'd recommend going with `void fun(int (&array)[4], char (&array2)[3])`, pass the array sizes or simply to pass references `std::vector` or `std::array`. If you allow for the arrays to decay, you introduce the possibility of passing null in addition introducing hard to maintain restrictions of minimal array sizes...

Comment: No using pointers in C++ should not be the first thing to consider. Note that you will have lost information when making this call. fun will have no way of knowing the size of the input and all kinds of things can go wrong as a result of that. What you are describing can be found in a "C" book, but should not have any place in a "C++" book